# How to remove footline on the title page of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using the default theme, and use the following to customize the footline,

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{.5cm}\scriptsize{\insertshorttitle
\hspace*{50pt} \hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{.5cm}}\\
\vspace{9pt}}
```

I don't like it also appears on the title page. Is there a simple way not to show it on the first page?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can redefine `footline` locally for the title frame; I also modified the `framenumber` counter so that the frames including the footline start from one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{.5cm}\scriptsize{\insertshorttitle
\hspace*{50pt} \hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{.5cm}}\\
\vspace{9pt}} 

\author{An Author}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}
A frame with footline
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of ``\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}``, you can tag the frames you don't want to count, ``\begin{frame}[label=intro,noframenumbering]``

Comment: Just to add: @PatrickT 's method is actually better, since using  `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` will cause the final slide number to be different from the total number of frames (e.g. when using `\insertframenumber` and `\inserttotalframenumber`)

Answer (score 15):

Here is solution via the `plain` option of frame environment (this solution works even with the `ignorenonframetext` option).

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{.5cm}\scriptsize{\insertshorttitle
\hspace*{50pt} \hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{.5cm}}\\
\vspace{9pt}} 

\author{An Author}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A frame with footline
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help me. After the same way removing the headline in my titlepage but there is an white space instead of the headline. How to fill it by the same coloes that I am using for my template background.

Comment: It works for me also with out the `ignorenonframetext` option.

Comment: @djhurio This solution works with or without the `ignorenonframetext` option...

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a custom footline with `\setbeamertemplate` you can actually exclude footline generation right in the template by using the following LaTeX condition structure:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \ifnum \theframenumber=1
        % This is the title frame, do nothing

    \else
        % These would be all the following frames
        % <<<Your template code goes here>>>
    \fi
}
```