# Creating a custom Beamer theme. Need to remove the footline for the title page only

Tags: beamer, header-footer

First of all, I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/how-to-remove-footline-on-the-title-page-of-beamer-slides) and it's really *not* what I'm asking: the solution given there is to issue

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
```

in a localized group containing the `\titlepage` frame. That's not what I want. As the title says, I'm creating a custom theme and I don't want to leave the suppression of the footline on the title page up to my end users. How can I go about suppressing the footline just for the title page?

Note that I already tried

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    % my definitions here
}
```

and it didn't work.

I know that the etiquette around here is to post a MWE, but I'm not really sure what I need to post in this case. If you need me to post parts of my definition, I'll gladly do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a presentation using your theme always has a title page, which is usually the first page, then one can define the template for `footline` to be different for the first page.

To implement this, one can use the `\ifnum` expression:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}
{
    \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
      <definition of footline style on page 1>
    \else
      <definition of footline style on other pages>
    \fi
}
```

This will define a template for `footline`, such that page 1 has a potentially different footline style from other pages. `\insertpagenumber` inserts the current page number into the template, which is checked by `\ifnum` to see if it's page 1. Then the appropriate clause of the "then-else" statement will be executed depending the truth value of the expression "the current page number is 1".

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}
{
    \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{}%
        % empty environment to raise height
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    \else
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    \fi
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[my footline]

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
This is a normal frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Please drop by and leave an explanation when you get time: I'm clueless when it comes to TeX/LaTeX programming and I could really benefit from an explanation. If you start wondering why a clueless guy is making a custom theme, it's because the lab I'm working in is forcing everyone to use the same (Power Point) template for all group seminars and I simply can't do Power Point! So I'm currently trying to replicate this theme.

Comment: @JosephR.: I updated the answer with some explanation. Hope it's clearer now `:)`

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please add explanations for `\leavemode` and `\vskip0pt`?

Comment: @JosephR.: `\leavevmode` causes the box to be in horizontal mode (note that you left out a "v" between "leave" and "mode"). According to the Beamer manual, this is inserted automatically when at the beginning of a Beamer box. I've tried removing it, and it didn't cause me any trouble. The same goes with `\vskip0pt`, which basically instructs TeX to add vertical space equal to `0pt` below the current line. This seems to be something that is harmless to remove.

Comment: @JosephR.: My definition of the template was modified using an existing template. You can find them at your local TeXMF tree, a path similar to `<local TeXMF tree>/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/`. There you'll find information on how some of the existing templates are defined, and then you can modify them to your own needs.

Comment: Note: I needed to use `\ifnum \insertframenumber=1` instead of `\ifnum \insertpagenumber=1`.