# Custom Beamer Theme: Set normal font size

Tags: beamer, fontsize, themes

As a follow up to [an earlier question I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142881/creating-a-custom-beamer-theme-need-to-remove-the-footline-for-the-title-page-o), I need to be able to set the normal font size to 20pt for a Beamer presentation. The catch is, I can't use

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
```

because I want to set this font size inside a custom theme that the end users can just load without needing to supply the extra `[20pt]`.

I already tried

```
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=20pt}
```

but no joy!

Comment: Have you tried something like `\setbeamerfont{normal text}{series=\normalfont, size=\fontsize{20}{24}}` or `\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}` in your beamer theme?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the suggestions. Neither one worked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code from [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142891/36296):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}
{
    \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{}%
        % empty environment to raise height
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    \else
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    \fi
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[my footline]

\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
This is a normal frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]