# Beamer style file: footline drops out of slide if used only from slide 2 on

Tags: beamer, header-footer, package-writing

I'm in the process of creating a style file for a Beamer presentation. Most things are straight forward but I have some issues with the footline. In particular, I don't want a footline on the title page but it should appear in all following slides. I follow basically the approach in: [Creating a custom Beamer theme. Need to remove the footline for the title page only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142881/creating-a-custom-beamer-theme-need-to-remove-the-footline-for-the-title-page-o).

However, I get the issue that my footline is not correctly aligned with the bottom of the slide. It actually drops out below and only roughly a third is still visible. I found a possible solution in [How to remove footline on the title page of beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/how-to-remove-footline-on-the-title-page-of-beamer-slides).
But here I need to change the actual beamer slides tex file which I want to avoid if possible. Everything should be defined in my *.sty file.

I tried to figure out the reason of this issue with no luck. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance for any tips.

I tried to compile a (not so) minimal working example to show the effect.
At the top I define my custom footline 'Ffootline' and there are two versions, the first is working by showing the footline on all slides (commented out in MWE). The second shows this partly covered footline.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DEFINE CUSTOM FOOTLINE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Ffootline}{%
  \insertsection % The left end of the footline
  \hfill
  \insertfooter % The center
  \hfill
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
} % And the right end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION I: working
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
%   \usebeamerfont{structure}
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{footlinecolor}%
%     \Tiny\hspace*{4mm} \Ffootline \hspace{4mm}
%   \end{beamercolorbox}
% }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION I: end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION II: NOT working
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This removes the footline from the title page but then it is too low on the others
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \ifnum \thepage=1 
  {
    % Don't add a Footline
  } 
  \else 
  {
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{footlinecolor}%
      \Tiny\hspace*{4mm} \Ffootline \hspace{4mm}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
  \fi
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION II: END
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% STUFF sucht that MEW compiles:
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Supress navigation baar
% Slides Content
\title{Title Page Title}
\author{Main author,}
\institute{Our Lab}
\newcommand{\insertfooter}{Custom Footline Text - bla bla bla}
\begin{document}
%--------------
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
%--------------
\section*{Introduction}
%--------------
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Project}
  Some content
\end{frame}
%--------------
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution I can think is using `[plain]` template for `title page`. This template suppresses headers and footers, therefore how `footline` is defined doesn't matter. xlr8t doesn't explain if this option has been considered.

Another solution which works in this case consists in inserting an empty `beamercolorbox` for title page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DEFINE CUSTOM FOOTLINE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Ffootline}{%
  \insertsection % The left end of the footline
  \hfill
  \insertfooter % The center
  \hfill
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
} % And the right end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION I: working
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
%   \usebeamerfont{structure}
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{footlinecolor}%
%     \Tiny\hspace*{4mm} \Ffootline \hspace{4mm}
%   \end{beamercolorbox}
% }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION I: end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION II: NOT working   %<--------- Now it works
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This removes the footline from the title page but then it is too low on the others
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\ifnum\thepage=1
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{footlinecolor}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{footlinecolor}%
        \Tiny\hspace*{4mm} \Ffootline \hspace*{4mm}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% VERSION II: END
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% STUFF sucht that MEW compiles:
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Supress navigation baar
% Slides Content
\title{Title Page Title}
\author{Main author,}
\institute{Our Lab}
\newcommand{\insertfooter}{Custom Footline Text - bla bla bla}
\begin{document}
%--------------
\begin{frame}%[plain]  %<------[plain] could be another solution
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
%--------------
\section*{Introduction}
%--------------
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Project}
  Some content
\end{frame}
%--------------
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Project}
  Some content
\end{frame}
%--------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ignasi, this was it. Kind of obvious now. ;) I guess it has to do how the size of the slide gets calculated (prob. based on the first slide).

Comment: @xlr8t In fact I also don't know why it works, but I remembered to have seen some empty `beamercolorboxes`, tried, ... and worked! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is rather dated, but I found another solution that I like a bit more. It's possible to customize templates for individual frames (or groups of frames) by overriding them inside curly braces. In this case, I set it to empty just for the first frame:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DEFINE CUSTOM FOOTLINE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Ffootline}{%
  \insertsection % The left end of the footline
  \hfill
  \insertfooter % The center
  \hfill
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
} % And the right end

% Declare constant footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{footlinecolor}%
  \Tiny\hspace*{4mm} \Ffootline \hspace{4mm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%% STUFF such that MEW compiles:
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Supress navigation baar
% Slides Content
\title{Title Page Title}
\author{Main author,}
\institute{Our Lab}
\newcommand{\insertfooter}{Custom Footline Text - bla bla bla}
\begin{document}
%--------------
{
  % Erase the footline on this frame
  % Made local by enclosing it in a group
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
}
%--------------
\section*{Introduction}
%--------------
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Project}
  Some content
\end{frame}
%--------------
\end{document}
```

(See [an example on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wtzmmhkyvbck))